# How to set fixed fps of process for some time (game)?

Tags: c++, winapi

Consider I want to create my own version of rivatuner. I want to implement fixed fps feature, which limitates fps of any game (don't have access to games source code). How to achieve it?
That's the exact way how I connect to the process:

```
PROCESSENTRY32 entry;
entry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

HANDLE snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL);

if (Process32First(snapshot, &entry) == TRUE)
{
    while (Process32Next(snapshot, &entry) == TRUE)
    {
        if (stricmp(entry.szExeFile, "target.exe") == 0)
        {  
            HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, entry.th32ProcessID);

            // Do stuff..

            CloseHandle(hProcess);
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe to make it more clear I want it to work similar to Rivatuner from msi afterbuner app (setting fixed fps)

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to "freeze" any random game you're playing? It's not for some game you're writing yourself?

Comment: _"Consider I have code that connects to process ..."_ Start to elaborate here. How do you _"connect"_ this game process? Is there a callback API you're using??

Comment: Maybe freeze is wrong word, I want to either set fixed fps for some time or freeze it

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I just do it by HANDLE from winapi

Comment: @szefitoo You cannot simply inject some of your own code having a process handle at hand. The things you can do with it, are reasonably restricted by the available functions from the winapi.

Comment: @szefitoo If you're at editing, show us the code how you're actually connecting the game process please! The part how you retrieve that handle.

Comment: Have you tried any of the many "cheat" programs that can hook into games? And what is the *actual* problem you're trying to solve? Why do you need to set a fixed FPS or "freeze" it?

Comment: Because in some cases there is no point for game to display 200 fps, sometimes I want to limit it to lower value like 30 or so.

Comment: Many games do have an option to limit the FPS as a way to increase quality in other parts (shadows, lights, etc.). Beyond that I don't really see a problem with a game drawing as fast as it can.

Comment: But If I want to make something similar to rivatuner, which sets fixed fps and I wonder how to do it.

Comment: So I want an app that is able to set all games fps to 30 for example.

Comment: @szefitoo that's just nonsense, there's no such API you could generally address with _all_ games. These are implementation details, which aren't controllable in a consistent manner.

Comment: So how does rivatuner does it then?@πάνταῥεῖ

Comment: if you look at [the rivatuner home page](https://www.guru3d.com/content-page/rivatuner.html), you'll see that they have to keep updating a database. It's just a big list of special-cases.

Comment: how does rivatuner works: https://www.guru3d.com/content-page/rivatuner-faq.html